# How to understand output from "ssh -O check" in bash scripts?

Tags: ssh

I want to check the master process listening on `ssh.sock` is still alive.
Currently I'm checking whether the exit code returned by `ssh -S ssh.sock -O check <my-server>` is zero, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to handle this problem and I can't find any documentation. The master process is supposed to have `ServerAliveInterval=20`, so that it will die if the connection fails. Is there any case in which the return code would be non-zero, but the process itself would be alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to try is to initiate process (`ssh -MS ssh.sock <my-server>`), remove socket and try how will it behave. With working connection:

```
$ ssh -S ssh.sock -O check <my-server>
Master running (pid=24314)
$ echo $?
0
```

When there is no socket, you will get something like this:

```
$ ssh -S ssh.sock -O check <my-server>
Control socket connect(ssh.sock): No such file or directory
$echo $?
255
```

I believe handling the return code is the correct way.

> Is there any case in which the return code would be non-zero, but the process itself would be alive?

As in the previous example, when the socket is removed for some reason, your connection is alive, but you can't check it from "outside" and you can't connect new sessions to it.

Comment: You you mind detailing a bit more about MS and ssh.sock socket? While I am fairly used to ssh, and have been tinkering with it, I still I am a bit of loss here. He the OP devising a way to test for some problems losing the socket?

Comment: `-M` is creation of master process, `-S` is the socket path, shortcut for `ControlMaster` and `ControlPath` from `ssh_config`. More problems should never happen. When the connection is broken, both sides get noticed and end (with removing the socket).

Comment: Interesting. I do have dealt slightly with that using ControlPersist

Comment: `ControlPersist` extends this behaviour over the end of the first connection, which is the only difference